# How to delete .sqlite3 file i.e. the database file in SWIFT?

Tags: database, sqlite, swift3, sqlite.swift

I'm using [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) library in my iOS app for database needs. I'm using more than one database with different names. I'm doing it fine no problems. At one point I need to delete the `.sqlite3` file i.e., the whole database file when it's no longer needed. I'm a newbie to `Swift3`. So I don't know how to delete the database. My app has a database called `AccountsDB` to store the number of profiles. Each profile has a database with it's name. When user deletes one profile I need to delete the database with that name too. This is my scenario. Please guide me to achieve my task. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to delete the `sqlite3` file and not the table ?

Comment: @NiravD yes, I no longer needed that database.

Comment: @NiravD let me try. thanks.

Comment: Please note that there might be `AccountsDB.sqlite3-journal`, `*-wal`, or `*-shm` files, which also need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FileManager` to delete the physical file from your device. I assume you know (or can retrieve) the path to the SQLite DB file, right? In that case, if `url` is the file URL to your file:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
do {
    try fm.removeItem(at:url)
} catch {
    NSLog("Error deleting file: \(url)")
}
```

Comment: let me try and revert. thanks